# How to index (subset) over a list of data.frames

Tags: r, list, dataframe, lapply

I got a list of several data.frames and I want to remove the first 2 columns from each of the data.frames. I did it as follows, but feel this could be more R-ish.

```
data(mtcars)
data(iris)
myList <- list(A = mtcars, B = iris)
# helper function
removeCols <- function(df,vec) {
res <- df[,-vec]
}
lapply(myList,removeCols,1:2)
```

Obviously this does the job, but to me it seems like i must have missed something here (such as using an operator within lapply, cause it's technically a function too). 
However, the major disadvantage of this approach is that you need a little helper function for every little task you want to do to all elements of that list.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code is perfectly good R.  But you have two alternative options:

1. Use an anonymous function - this is a general solution
2. Use the `[` operator - specific to this case

Your original:

```
xx <- lapply(myList,removeCols,1:2)
```

An anonymous function:

```
yy <- lapply(myList, function(df, vec){df[,-vec]}, 1:2)
```

Use the `[` operator:

```
zz <- lapply(myList, "[", -(1:2))
```

These yield identical results

```
identical(xx, yy)
[1] TRUE

identical(xx, zz)
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: +1, thanks Andrie, your 2nd option is what I was lookin for. I was actually effin close when I tried `"[["` before.

Comment: @hans0l0 I'm glad I could help. Keep in mind that `[[` returns a single element only. So it has its place, but not in this case!

Answer (score 4):

The only thing I can imagine at the moment to be more R-ish is to make it shorter and get rid of the helper-function.

```
data(mtcars)
data(iris)
myList <- list(A = mtcars, B = iris)
lapply(myList,function(x) x[,-(1:2)])
```

If you asking for a direct way to modify something:

```
myList[[1]][,-(1:2)]
```

But as lists are a quite open structure with no requirements to its content you can not index over its contents, as they can be really different. However if your tow data sets have the same dimension (nxm) than you can combine them to an 3d-array on which all the known indexing tricks will work.